# Problemas Con Stored Procedure de MySQL para comparar Insertar o Actualizar

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de implementar un **`Stored Procedure`** el cual agregara un registro nuevo o habilitara un registro ya existente cambiando la columna `Status` a 1.

**Código Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE Ejemplo(IN _Department VARCHAR(100))
 BEGIN
  DECLARE variable VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT "";
  SELECT Department_Name INTO variable FROM department WHERE Department_Name = _Department;
  IF (variable = _Department) THEN UPDATE department SET Status = 1 WHERE Department_Name = _Department  ;
  ELSE INSERT INTO department (Department_Name, Status) VALUES (_Department)  ;
  END IF;
  END
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Opción 1**

Como no indicas el uso de una llave primaria, el proceso de eliminación o actualización produce un error; como lo puedes comprobar en la documentación de MySQL que dice<sup>1</sup>:

> If this option is enabled, UPDATE and DELETE statements that do not use a key in the WHERE clause or a LIMIT clause produce an error. In addition, restrictions are placed on SELECT statements that produce (or are estimated to produce) very large result sets. If you have set this option in an option file, you can use --skip-safe-updates on the command line to override it. For more information about this option, see Using Safe-Updates Mode (--safe-updates).

Que se puede traducir como:

> Si esta opción esta habilitada, las sentencias UPDATE y DELETE que no usen una clave en la sentencia WHERE o LIMIT producirán un error, además, se localizan restricciones a las sentencias SELECT que producen (o son estimadas que producen) grandes conjuntos de resultados. Si ha configurado esta opción en un archivo de opciones, puedes usar --skip-safe-updates en la línea de comandos para anularlo.

Y como en la misma documentación<sup>2</sup> indica deberás desactivar dicha restricción con el siguiente comando:

```
SET sql_safe_updates=0
```

**Opción 2**

O bien puedes permitir en los argumentos que reciba tu PA que el usuario ingrese un `id` que sería la llave primaria:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE Ejemplo(IN _Id INT)
```

Y en las 2 sentencias donde empleas una condición de filtro por medio de la clausula `WHERE` modificarlo del siguiente modo:

```
WHERE TuLlavePrimaria = _Id
```

Estoy asumiendo que tu `PK` es `Id` y de tipo `INT`; en caso contrario realiza los cambios necesario a mi propuesta

O prueba dejando tu `WHERE` como esta pero también agrega el `id` como te mencioné

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE Ejemplo(IN _Department VARCHAR(100), IN _Id INT)
 BEGIN
  DECLARE variable VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT "";
  SELECT Department_Name INTO variable 
  FROM department 
  WHERE Department_Name = _Department
  AND tuLlavePrimaria = _Id;
  IF (variable = _Department) THEN 
    UPDATE department 
    SET Status = 1 
    WHERE Department_Name = _Department
    AND tuLlavePrimaria = _Id;;
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO department (Department_Name, Status) 
    VALUES (_Department)  ;
  END IF;
 END
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [sql update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates)
- <sup>2</sup> [sql safe update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates)

Comment: El motivo por el cual no estoy utilizando la PK, es porque Estoy desactivando el status de mi fila en lugar de eliminarla, lo que busco es que si el usuario quiere volver a dar de alta un registro con el mismo nombre solo lo active y si no existe que lo inserte. Como puedo utilizar el `SET sql_safe_updates=0` en mi consulta.

Comment: Tendrás que ejecutar dicho comando antes de tu consulta, eso debería anular el comportamiento que tiene al momento y permitirte la intención

Comment: Probado y Funcionando.