# Error Code: 1175 mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

estoy intentando hacer una consulta que consiste en Actualizar el precio del proveedor en aquellos productos en los cuales no tienen valor en PrecioProveedor (colocar el valor del precio de venta menos el
15%), pero al momento de ejecutar la consulta me manda el siguiente error:

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.   0.000 sec
```

Y esta es la consulta que estoy ejecutando

```
UPDATE Productos SET PrecioProveedor = ROUND(PrecioProveedor * 0.15) where PrecioProveedor=0;
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problemas Con Stored Procedure de MySQL para comparar Insertar o Actualizar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/337147/problemas-con-stored-procedure-de-mysql-para-comparar-insertar-o-actualizar)

Comment: Eso no es, @BetaM

Comment: Por lo visto tu consulta no esta siendo filtrada por una columa clave (en WHERE). Pero mas alla de eso, tu consulta no producira cambios ya que usas el mismo campo como fuente (PrecioProveedor)

Comment: Por qué no @AlfaBravo si el mensaje de error es el mismo?

Comment: 1. El error que reportan acá no es con un SP. 2. Está chocando con una característica de MySQL.

Comment: Eso lo se @AlfaBravo pero en parte de la respuesta se sugiere lo mismo (where) que en la respuesta que tú enlazas

Comment: entonces que me recomiendan hacer?

Comment: Puedes revisar lo que te enlace y lo que aporta @Alfa, todo te ayudará

Comment: Es verdá, @BetaM. Ya vi bien la respuesta aceptada y sí ayuda.

Comment: @FatimaJimenezSandoval segura que quieres redondear los precios que sean cero, multiplicados por 0.15?

Comment: no que sean multiplicados por el 0.15

Comment: Cero por 0.15 sigue siendo cero. _¿Estás segura de la consulta?_ es el nombre del error 1175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un atributo tanto de MySQL como del cliente que estás usando, MySQL workbench, para que no se ejecuten consultas que tengan el potencial de dañar todos tus datos, muchos de ellos, algo así.

En tu tabla productos seguramente (espero) hay una PK. La idea es que tu consulta UPDATE tenga en el WHERE una condición que aluda a esa PK, así el motor pensará que estás haciendo algún tipo de selectividad, buscando un subconjunto no-tan-extenso de registros.

El camino sano es hacer una consulta que no afecte toda la tabla. Tu consulta toma muchos registros (los que tengan precio en cero) y les cambia ese valor. (De paso, revisa la lógica porque `0 * 0.15 = 0` y creo que no sirve de mucho).

Si uno de verdad quiere hacer ese tipo de consultas con afectación masiva, incluye en el WHERE una condición que aluda a la PK.

Ejemplo:

```
UPDATE Productos 
SET PrecioProveedor = ROUND(PrecioProveedor * 0.15) 
WHERE (PrecioProveedor = 0 AND PK_Producto <> 0);
```

Si tienes sangre fría, necesitas hacer un update masivo, *estás segura de ello* y te enreda la vida correr la consulta usando la PK de alguna forma, se desactiva la directiva en tu cliente:

> ```
> Edit --> Preferences
> Clic en "SQL Editor" y deselecciona "Safe Updates"
> Query --> Reconnect to Server // logout y luego login
> Ejecutar la consulta
> ```

Pero ese no es el camino recomendado. Ese error está ahí por algo.

Respuesta elaborada siguiendo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28316067/236345).