# Sumar una cantidad a cada valor de una columna en SQL

Tags: mysql

Quiero **sumar +10** a cada columna de una tabla de una base de datos en SQL.

La base de datos se llama `eoi_test`, la tabla `sets` y la columna que deseo modificar `year`

Tengo experiencia en otros lenguajes y con lo poco que sé, se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE eoi_test.sets
SET year = year+10;
```

Ejecuté el código suponiendo que obtendría un error, el cual es:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect

¿Cómo puedo sumar 10 a cada valor de la columna `year`?

Comment: de qué tipo de dato es la columna `year`? Para preguntas sobre BD, procura indicar la estructura de la tabla o tablas sobre las que operas e, idealmente, datos de prueba y la salida esperada. Lo otro, pon los errores completos, no simplemente un resumen. A veces cuatro, ocho o veinte pares de ojos ven más que uno

Comment: Aparte de saber el tipo de dato, ¿qué error da esa query?

Comment: esa query deberia andar... lo que ves es un warning para qu no modifiques toda la tabla sin querer

Comment: Los valores de la columna son integer,ahora añado el error que me da la query en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿O esta otra https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379704/error-code-1175-mysql?

Comment: Creo que no responde directamente a mi pregunta, pero me ha ayudado. Tenía que desactivar la restricción:        SET sql_safe_updates=0;

Comment: @JuanLuis el problema en principio es el mismo pero en contextos diferentes y no necesariamente tienes que desactivar, como se indica en ambas lo solucionarías con el uso de `WHERE` también

Comment: o sea, esto es pura y exclusivamente un problema de tu ide?

Comment: Tienes razón @BetaM, el problema es el mismo. De hecho acabo de averiguar que no tengo que incluir el WHERE, basta con desactivar la restricción ¿Dicha restricción es para evitar hacer cambios por error?¿Debería cerrar esta pregunta? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta a usar `WHERE 1` que es cierto para todos los registros, no necesitas deshabilitar safe_updates, y con seguridad **el motor no chilla** si te exige que uses una columna de clave pon la condición clave no nula